# dicord py issue displaying bracketed values in embed

Tags: python, discord.py

trying to make a nice embed for my diceroll command to output to but my issue is that the embed keeps just displaying raw value rather than the int value i'm trying to get (image for reference bellow) i’ve tried to find workarounds or solutions online but cant find anything that works or is specific to my issue

```py
@bot.command()
async def rolldice(ctx):
    messagetwo = await ctx.send("Choose a number:\n**4**, **6**, **8**, **10**, **12**, **20** ")
    user = ctx.message.author.display_name
    
    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author

    try:
        messageone = await bot.wait_for("message", check = check, timeout = 30.0)
        m = messageone.content

        if m != "4" and m != "6" and m != "8" and m != "10" and m != "12" and m != "20":
            await ctx.send("Sorry, invalid choice.")
            return
        
        coming = await ctx.send("Here it comes...")
        asyncio.sleep(1)
        await coming.delete()
        await messagetwo.delete()
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=2)
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title="{user}'s Dice",color=0x00ffff)
        embedVar.add_field(name="rolled", value="D{m}", inline=True)
        embedVar.add_field(name="landed", value="{random.randint(1, int(m))}", inline=True)
        embedVar.set_footer(text='Booty Police | Dungeon Dice',icon_url="http://canvaswrite.com/PI/pybot/attachments/server-icon-full.png")
        await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)
        await ctx.send(f"{user} rolled a **D{m}** and got a **{random.randint(1, int(m))}**")
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await messageone.delete()
        await ctx.send("Procces has been canceled because you didn't respond in **30** seconds.")
```

[image: embed displaying raw values vs the correct format bellow it in a ctx message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to use f-string but forgot to place the `f` before the string. Without the `f` it will not format the string. Here's a guide on [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) if you want to read more about them

```py
x = 3 
print(f"This is the value {x}")

>>> This is the value 3
```

so in order for your code to work you need to just prepend the string with an f. the fixed code would look something like this:

```py
@bot.command()
async def rolldice(ctx):
    messagetwo = await ctx.send("Choose a number:\n**4**, **6**, **8**, **10**, **12**, **20** ")
    user = ctx.message.author.display_name
    
    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author

    try:
        messageone = await bot.wait_for("message", check = check, timeout = 30.0)
        m = messageone.content

        if m != "4" and m != "6" and m != "8" and m != "10" and m != "12" and m != "20":
            await ctx.send("Sorry, invalid choice.")
            return
        
        coming = await ctx.send("Here it comes...")
        asyncio.sleep(1)
        await coming.delete()
        await messagetwo.delete()
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=2)
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title=f"{user}'s Dice",color=0x00ffff)
        embedVar.add_field(name="rolled", value=f"D{m}", inline=True)
        embedVar.add_field(name="landed", value=f"{random.randint(1, int(m))}", inline=True)
        embedVar.set_footer(text='Booty Police | Dungeon Dice',icon_url="http://canvaswrite.com/PI/pybot/attachments/server-icon-full.png")
        await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)
        await ctx.send(f"{user} rolled a **D{m}** and got a **{random.randint(1, int(m))}**")
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await messageone.delete()
        await ctx.send("Procces has been canceled because you didn't respond in **30** seconds.")
```

Comment: you’re very right i just noticed this while going over my code again scratching my head and audibly gasped when i noticed my error thank you

Comment: @newtboot no worries, if it's alright please accept the answer in order to mark it as complete